# Shell reverse search fails each time whenever I restart the shell

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

Well as per title. Say I type something in shell:

```
echo hello
```

The reverse search works. Except it stops working the moment I close the shell and reopen it. (Failed revers-i-search)

It actually works if I make myself root by typing `sudo -s`. So I think the problem is with permissions on the history? How do I fix this though?

The history file permission are (from `ls -l`):

```
-rw------- 1 root root 70515 sep 11 12:50 /home/paul/.bash_history
```

what should they be and how should i set those?

Comment: Check the permissions of the file that bash uses to keep track of history: `~/.bash_history`. If that file does not exist, try `echo $HISTFILE` and check the permissions of that file. HISTFILE is set in your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @Adriaan I can indeed see the file is owned by root. but what should the permissions be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file should be owned by you. Since it is owned by `root` instead for some reason, you cannot write to it so your shell history cannot be saved. Just fix the ownership and permissions:

```
sudo chown paul:paul /home/paul/.bash_history
chmod a+r /home/paul/.bash_history
```

After this, the file should look like this:

```
$ ls -l /home/paul/.bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paukl 70515 sep 11 12:50 /home/paul/.bash_history
```